# Trying to get the most of the random element possibily from first 4 items in array php

Tags: php

Hi am having 10 elements in array . Am trying to get my random element mostly from first 5 elements. Which means random element appearance from first 5 elements should be much greater than next 5 elements

```
 $arr    = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
   $random = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
```

Am using above one to get the random element normally

Comment: _"random element appearance from first 5 elements should be much greater than next 5 elements"_ - So, not that random then?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? If yes, show it to us. If no, you need to do that first. SO isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function `rand(min_num, max_num)`:

```
function rand5($array) {
     $part = rand(1, 10);
     return ($part > 3) ? $array[rand(0, 4)] : $array[rand(5, 9)];
}
$arr    = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$random = rand5($arr);
```

Comment: I want to chose random from second 5 also but it should be only some times

Comment: I would recommend that you re-read the question.

Comment: I changed code @patel

Comment: it means the random number should be 70% from the first elements and 30% from second 5 elements

Comment: Try it. I think it is what you want @patel

Answer (score 0):

Try this **simple and easy** code :-

```
$arr = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
$rand = rand(0,9);
echo $arr[($rand <= 6 ? ($rand%5) : $rand)];
```

You just have to get the random number between 0 to 9 and divide that number in 70%(0-6) and 30%(7-9). If its greater than 5 then only use the remainder else directly get that number

Here is the fiddle :- https://3v4l.org/TWGJJ

Comment: @patel You can check my answer...